# Boost.spirit x3 compiler error when using semantic action in VS15

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am getting compiler error about not enough arguments. The code is reduced example code from spirit tutorial at:
[Spirit tutorial][1]

When I remove the [f] after int_, there are no errors and the code runs.
If I also add the forth parameter to parse function for the attribute, it also works and does get the attribute just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using:
Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

```
    Error   C2780   'auto main::<lambda_6800f15c010c4c6f910f02a29d8fc1e2>::operator ()(_T1 &) const': expects 1 arguments - 0 provided  feature_descriptor  c:\boost\boost_1_62_0\boost\spirit\home\x3\core\call.hpp    57
```

That's the error I get in the following code:

```
        /*=============================================================================
    Copyright (c) 2001-2015 Joel de Guzman

    Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
    file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
    =============================================================================*/
    // This is a reduced version of an example copied from Spirit tutorial at:
    // http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/semantic_actions.html

    #include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

    #include <iostream>


    int main()
    {
        using boost::spirit::x3::int_;
        using boost::spirit::x3::parse;


        { // example using C++14 lambda

            char const *first = "{44}", *last = first + std::strlen(first);
            auto f = [](auto& ctx) { std::cout << _attr(ctx) << std::endl; };
            parse(first, last, '{' >> int_[f] >> '}');
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest updating to VSC 2015 **Update 3** - it compiles fine using `Boost 1.60`.

Comment: I don't recommend Boost 1.60 for X3. For the simple reason X3 is experimental and had many starter issues or blatant missing features in previous releases. So, 1.62 or bust, and MSVC is simply not on the supported compilers list. Yet.

Comment: It works now. I got the **Update 3** and the code began to work.. Thanks @doqtor and @sehe!

Comment: I have to retract some of my enthusiasm, as soon as I tried a bit more involved Boost.Spirit construct, the VS2015 compilation failed. I have since switched to _GCC ver.6.1.0_ (with **Code Blocks** and MinGW) and have not had any issues.